# TSQL Group by two columns but result in the same row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have transaction data table in SQL Server 2012 such as:

```
Month   Type  
-----   -----
1       Paper
1       Paper
1       Mobile
2       Mobile
3       Paper
3       Mobile
```

If I group by Month I can easily count the occurrences of transactions:

```
SELECT Month, Count(*) 
FROM Transaction 
GROUP BY Month
```

If I group by Month and Type:

```
SELECT Month, Type, Count(Type) AS RowCount 
FROM Transaction 
GROUP BY Month,Type
```

I can break down the results and get counts for each type. However, the results are shown in distinct rows:

```
Month  Type     RowCount
------  -----   ---------
1      Paper    2
1      Mobile   1
2      Mobile   1
3      Paper    1
3      Mobile   1
```

Now what I really need is to know if it is possible to generate the below result via ONE query:

```
Month    Paper    Mobile
-------  -------  --------
1        2        1
2        0        1
3        1        1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are Paper and Mobile the only two types you will ever have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a CASE statement and SUM to do this:

```
Select
    Month,
    Sum(Case When Type = 'Paper'  Then 1 Else 0 End) As Paper,
    Sum(Case When Type = 'Mobile' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Mobile
From [transaction]
Group By Month
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3881/1)

Since you're using SQL Server 2012 you can use the IIF statement to make the code a bit more compact:

```
SELECT 
    Month,
    SUM(IIF(TYPE='Paper',1,0)) AS Paper,
    SUM(IIF(TYPE='Mobile',1,0)) AS Mobile
FROM [Transaction]
GROUP BY Month
```

Note that *transaction* is a keyword that you need to put in brackets.

If you have more types you can use dynamic sql to generate the correct code for all types.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT month,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Paper' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Paper,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Mobile' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Mobile
FROM t
GROUP BY month
```